# How to get xpath selector for dynamically loaded class

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Part of the class name is loaded dynamically ( ico-partly-cloudy)..I am trying to get this part only form 
source html

```
<div data-ng-class="'icon-' + day.icon + '-' + theme" class="forecast-icon ico-partly-cloudy" xpath="1"></div>
```

by using:

```
response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/@class=forcast-icon').extract()
```

I was looking to get the remaining part of the class attribute which changes dynamically. The above certainly does not do it

Comment: if it's loading dynamically, you can't get it via scrapy XPath. Try tools like selenium or splash.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/@class').extract_first().split('forecast-icon ')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler option using just xpath, change your xpath expression to:

```
//div[@data-ng-class][contains(@class,"forecast-icon")]/substring-after(@class,"forecast-icon ")
```

Answer (score 0):

thing you can do it with css like this

```
response.css('.forecast-icon.ico-partly-cloudy').get()
```

now i dont know how you get hte selection